# How to verify that the YourKit agent is installed properly on macOS using terminal with JDK 1.8+

Tags: java, macos, terminal, yourkit

I would like to verify that I have installed `YourKit` agent properly and I have it on my PATH. 
I am using:

```
macOS 10.14.4
java version "1.8.0_191"
```

Any thoughts how to verify that using the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to run "java -agentpath=full_path_to_libyjpagent.jnilib -version" command. If all is OK, you will see YourKit Java Profiler agent output together with the output of "java -version".

The output should look like:

```
[YourKit Java Profiler 2019.1-b113] Log file: /home/xxxx/.yjp/log/java-6519.log
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

More details is here https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/agent.jsp

Comment: I know this is silly question, but I can't find my `full_path_to_libyjpagent.jnilib`. 
is that the one ? $ pwd
/Applications/YourKit-Java-Profiler-2019.1.app/

Comment: In your case profiler agent library will be in /Applications/YourKit-Java-Profiler-2019.1.app/Contents/Resources/bin/mac directory.